# CORS config in node express and socket.io No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I have my API hosted on Heroku and the Angular webAPP in other server. I have a problem when integrating socket.io to the API, my calls to the api do not work and I get error 503, caused by some bad configuration of the CORS?

app.js (Node.js/Express hosted in heroku server)

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
//var port = 3000;

// Notification Real Time 
// http://4dev.tech/2017/12/tutorial-creating-a-realtime-notification-system-in-angular-and-nodejs/
var http = require('http');
var server = http.createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
io.set("origins", "*:*");

var socket_port = process.env.PORT || 8000;
server.listen(socket_port);
//server.listen(8000);

io.on('connection', function(socket) {
  socket.on('create notification', function( data ) {
    socket.broadcast.emit('new notification', data);
  });
});

/* ... more code ...*/

app.listen(port, ()=> {
    console.log('Node/Express: \x1b[32m%s\x1b[0m', 'online - port: '+ port);
});
```

In the chrome console shows the error:

> OPTIONS https://myapp-backend.herokuapp.com/login 503 (Service
>   Unavailable) Failed to load https://myapp-backend.herokuapp.com/login:
>   Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://my-domain.com' is therefore not allowed
>   access. The response had HTTP status code 503

## EDIT

If set `server.listen(8000);` get 404 error:

> GET https://myapp-backend.herokuapp.com/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=MEyiNar
>   404 (Not Found)

follow by:

> Failed to load
>   https://myapp-backend.herokuapp.com/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=MEyiNar:
>   The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response
>   must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is
>   'include'. Origin 'http://my-domain' is therefore not allowed access.
>   The credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is
>   controlled by the withCredentials attribute.

## UPDATE

It works great with this configuration, there was a problem with the ports

```
// Notification Real Time 
// http://4dev.tech/2017/12/tutorial-creating-a-realtime-notification-system-in-angular-and-nodejs/
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
// io.set("origins", "*:*");

io.on('connection', function(socket) {
  socket.on('create notification', function( data ) {
    socket.broadcast.emit('new notification', data);
  });
});
// var socket_port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
// server.listen(socket_port);
//server.listen(8000);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Browser uses `OPTIONS` method check few CROS. (Such as which methods are allowed)

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");

 // Add this
 if (req.method === 'OPTIONS') {

      res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'PUT, POST, PATCH, DELETE, OPTIONS');
      res.header('Access-Control-Max-Age', 120);
      return res.status(200).json({});
  }

  next();

});
```

[Checkout MDN for full details of `OPTIONS` method.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/OPTIONS)

**EDIT:**
I just noticed, here is another error that this app uses two different port in locally but in Heroku you'll get only one port.

**EDIT 2:**
Port issue has been fixed by user & this answer holds the actual answer of the question.

Comment: There is an another error that, you're using two different port. You should use one port.

Comment: I updated my question. Is it solved by getting two ports from heroku?

Comment: You can't use two port in one heroku app.

Comment: `require('socket.io').listen(server);` => this should not be

Comment: I do not understand, I sent a message to your facebook. Please check it.

Comment: Sorry! I don't use Facebook from few days. Join stackoverflow chat if you want.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172270/discussion-between-ritwick-dey-and-nicogaldo).

Answer (score -2):

Any HTTP method that might have implications on user data will first send an HTTP request by the OPTIONS method. Your cross-origin domain should send a custom header along and the server accepting the cross origin request should accept that header.

Whatever your actual request is will not be allowed to submit until the OPTIONS request is able to succeed.

For example, `http://my-domain.com` could add these headers to the request first:

```
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
Access-Control-Request-Headers: X-CUSTOM-HEADER, Content-Type
```

And `https://myapp-backend.herokuapp.com/login` should have this use specification:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://my-domain
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-CUSTOM-HEADER, Content-Type
Access-Control-Max-Age: 86400
```

Read about preflight requests here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Comment: Where should I add those headers on `my-domain.com`, in the `.htaccess`?. And in `app.js` you should add them to the `app.post` or where?